# mysql query unknown coulmn error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have following mysql query,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as pg_total 
FROM products p , prod_sub s 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT io.uni_id, count(io.uni_id) AS popular 
    FROM items_ord io GROUP BY io.uni_id ) as z 
ON z.uni_id = p.uni_id 
WHERE p_stock != 9 
AND p.cat_id = 'ct_54a2e9fed3689' 
AND p.uni_id = s.uni_id AND s.sub_id IN ('sb_54a2ea814a64d') 
GROUP BY p.uni_id 
ORDER BY z.popular DESC
```

However this query works fine,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as pg_total 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT io.uni_id, count(io.uni_id) AS popular 
    FROM items_ord io GROUP BY io.uni_id ) z 
ON z.uni_id = p.uni_id
WHERE p_stock != 9 
AND p.cat_id = 'ct_54a2e9fed3689' 
ORDER BY z.popular DESC
```

This query throws `Unknown column 'p.uni_id' in 'on clause'`. I can't find the problem.

Comment: You're table does not have the column `p.uni_id`.

Comment: Post the database structure as well.

Comment: The table have `uni_id`. please check my updated question.

Comment: @Akshay I'm sure that all tables have `uni_id` column. I'm not good at joins that's why can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Make a sqlfiddle, it will let us find the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `as` in     `FROM items_ord io GROUP BY io.uni_id ) z`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as pg_total 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT io.uni_id, count(io.uni_id) AS popular 
    FROM items_ord io GROUP BY io.uni_id ) as z 
ON z.uni_id = p.uni_id
WHERE p_stock != 9 
AND p.cat_id = 'ct_54a2e9fed3689' 
ORDER BY z.popular DESC
```

Comment: I've tried but still not working. I don't think it makes a difference if we put `as` or not.

Answer (score 0):

run this code and copy output and past in `sql` and run so, you get which column is unknown

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as pg_total 
FROM products p , prod_sub s 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT io.uni_id, count(io.uni_id) AS popular 
    FROM items_ord io GROUP BY io.uni_id ) as z 
ON z.uni_id = p.uni_id 
WHERE p_stock != 9 
AND p.cat_id = 'ct_54a2e9fed3689' 
AND p.uni_id = s.uni_id AND s.sub_id IN ('sb_54a2ea814a64d') 
GROUP BY p.uni_id 
ORDER BY z.popular DESC";
echo $sql; exit;
```